# Palette colour overrides Outline

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm making an app just to check out some of the new L APIs, and I'm particularly interested in the `FloatingActionButton` and the Palette colour generator. So I set a full screen `ImageView` to display an HTC wallpaper, I then extract one of the colours with `Palette` and set it as the background colour of my FAB. However, doing this removes the Outline from my FAB, so it's no longer circular.
I would like to know how, if possible, to stop the Palette overriding the Outline.

The Palette AsyncListener:

#### MyActivity.java

```
Palette.generateAsync(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.wallpapers_07),
     new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
          @Override
          public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
              PaletteItem item = palette.getLightVibrantColor();
              ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
              if (item != null) {
                  button.setBackgroundColor(item.getRgb());
              }
           }
     });
```

#### Outline in MyActivity.java

```
int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
Outline outline = new Outline();
outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
findViewById(R.id.fab).setOutline(outline);
```

#### FAB background drawable

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the background drawable (RippleDrawable) with a color (ColorDrawable). Instead, you want to change the color of the shape (GradientDrawable) contained with the background drawable.

Try changing the color filter instead:

```
findViewById(R.id.fab).getBackgroundDrawable().setColorFilter(
    new PorterDuffColorFilter(item.getRgb(), Mode.SRC_IN));
```

If you're changing the color often, you can just cache the color filter object and use setColor(int) followed by findViewById(R.id.fab).invalidate() to update the view.